# XmlSerializer in C#, deserialize a class decorated with multiple XmlElement with same name by a particular attribute?

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, xmlserializer, xml-attribute

I have a class which is decorated with XmlElement in a wrong way, but it has also attributes that could allow me to identify the fields I need.

I can only modify [IWantToSerializeThisAttribute] and add other attributes to MySerializableClass because any modification to property names or XmlElement names would involve heavy coding maintenance.

Here's how the class has been defined:

```
 [XmlRoot("ARandomXmlRoot")]
    public class MySerializableClass
    {

        //CAMPI DIR_DOCUMENTI
        //[MetadatoDocumentoAlfresco] è un attributo che serve per selezionare i campi per l'aggiornamento dati massivo su alfresco
        [IWantToSerializeThisAttribute]
        [XmlElement("DocumentCode")]
        public string DOC_CODE { get; set; }

        [IWantToSerializeThisAttribute]
        [XmlElement("DocumentId")]
        public string DOC_ID { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("DocumentCode")]
        public string DOC_CODE_FOR_EMPLOYEES { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("DocumentId")]
        public string DOC_ID_FOR_EMPLOYEES { get; set; }

    }
```

Now, if I do

```
XmlSerializer.Deserialize(xmlString, typeof(MySerializableClass));
```

I will get an error most probably because XmlSerializer is finding 2 times the

```
[XmlElement("DocumentCode")]
```

and sees it's a duplicate tag.

Anyway I have an

```
[IWantToSerializeThisAttribute]
```

that makes the 2 properties different.

Can I tell someway XmlSerializer.Deserialize to catch and valorize only the "IwantToSerializeThisAttribute" properties and ignore the others?

I cannot change serialization with XmlOverrideAttributes,  but maybe there is some way to do it during deserialization.

Thanks everyone

Comment: If the xml tag is occurring twice than you need an array : [XmlElement("DocumentId")]
        public List<string> DOC_ID { get; set; }

Comment: The obvious answer is delete the attribute, given you don't want it to be used. Why do you have an `XmlElement` attribute on a property you *don't* want to serialise?

Comment: Show us your xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with XmlOverrideAttributes and Reflection. Using LINQ just to make it short.

This worked for me:

```
 string XmlString = "<ARandomXmlRoot> XML HERE </ARandomXmlRoot>";
            XmlAttributeOverrides overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();

            //Select fields I DON'T WANT TO SERIALIZE because they throw exception
            string[] properties = (new MySerializableClass())
                .GetType().GetProperties()
                .Where(p => !Attribute.IsDefined(p, typeof(IWantToSerializeThisAttribute)))
                .Select(p => p.Name);

            //Add an XmlIgnore attribute to them
            properties.ToList().ForEach(field => overrides.Add(typeof(MySerializableClass), field, new XmlAttributes() { XmlIgnore = true }));

            MySerializableClass doc = new MySerializableClass();

            XmlSerializer serializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MySerializableClass), overrides);
            using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlString))
            {
                doc = (MySerializableClass)serializerObj.Deserialize(reader);
            };
```

Cheers

Comment: This is what I was looking for, because allows me to do dynamic xml serialization/deserialization excluding fields only when I need it

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand correctly but let me try to give you some options:

> Can I tell someway XmlSerializer.Deserialize to catch and valorize only the "IwantToSerializeThisAttribute" properties and ignore the others?

If you want to serialize only specific properties use `[XmlIgnore]` attribute for the properties you want to omit. But if for some reason (`DOC_CODE_FOR_EMPLOYEES` and `DOC_ID_FOR_EMPLOYEES`)

But if you mean that it should be only omitted while deserializing, but serialization should still be done for all properties I'd think about implementing `IXmlSerializable`. This way you can specifically provide how would you like to read/write your xml.

Comment: Solved with XmlAttributeOverrides